# loop each matching span

Tags: jquery, each

I have a couple of span classes and I want to update their values individually. I am using JQuery's $each but I am unable to make it work

```
<span class='my-span'>hello</span>
<span class='my-span'>world</span>
<span class='my-span'>from</span>
<span class='my-span'>my</span>
<span class='my-span'>code</span>
```

And the js part is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('span.chat-datetime').each(function(){
    $(this).innerText = "modified";
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fwcs5x1k/

Any explaination why it is not working? and how to make it work? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should use [$().text()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_text.asp) method to modify text and the selector class you are using doesn't exist in dom .Try this it works

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.my-span').each(function() {

    $(this).text("modified");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='my-span'>hello</span>
<span class='my-span'>world</span>
<span class='my-span'>from</span>
<span class='my-span'>my</span>
<span class='my-span'>code</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. $().text() did the trick. Can you please explain why `$(".my-span")[0].innerText = "testing"` works and the same doesn't work within the each loop ?

Comment: May be because you are combining pure js and jquery .Please accept the answer if it works thanks @Raza